# How to get selected file path in Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have implemented dropzone.js in my web application. I am trying to get the full path of the file which the user selects. Everything works perfectly as of now, expect to get the path.  the `progress` and `success` function works correctly.

I am trying to use the `sending` function but it does not give me any response and the function is not triggered.

```
var dropZoneObj = jQuery("#drop").dropzone({
    filesName: 'dfiles',
    url: "{{action('SomeController@processAttachments',['pid' => $pid])}}",
    text: '+ Add more attachment',
    width: 250,
    height: 100,
    progressBarWidth: '100%',
    maxFiles: 10,
    uploadMode: 'single',
    maxFileSize: '5MB',
    allowedFileTypes: 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,xls,xlsx,doc,docx,csv,txt,pdf',
    params:{
        '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}",
    },
    // this is not getting called
    sending: function(file, xhr, data){
        console.log(file, xhr, data);
    },
    progress: function(file, xhr, data){
        jQuery('#defectSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    },
    success: function(res, index){
       console.log(res, index);
    }
});
```

I expect the output to be the file name in the `sending` function but I am getting empty.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37961706/2943218

Comment: init doesn't get called @CarstenLøvboAndersen